# VueJS @google-cloud/logging-winston (intermediate value).GoogleAuth is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, logging, winston, google-cloud-logging

I am trying to add **@google-cloud/logging-winston** to my VueJS project. I followed these https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/logging-winston and https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-winston-quickstart very closely.

I am getting:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value) (intermediate value) (intermediate value).GoogleAuth is not a constructor
     at new Logging(index.js ? 221c: 137: 1)
     at new LoggingCommon(common.js ? bc26 : 94: 1)
     at new LoggingWinston(index.js ? 1856 : 113: 1)
```

Here's my code:

```
const winston = require('winston');

const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

// error here
const gcloudWinston = new LoggingWinston();
```

I don't understand how the imported constructor would throw a TypeError (for another constructor of GoogleAuth).

Comment: @google-cloud/logging-winston has as its dependencies several packages, including one called google-auth-library. Check if all the dependencies get installed.

Comment: yes, all dependencies are installed.  any more thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The Root Cause Analysis for this issue would be that you might be using an older version of googleapis library which doesn’t have GoogleAuth as a constructor.

The `TypeError GoogleAuth is not a constructor` can be resolved by updating the googleapis library to the latest version.

Please run the below command to update the googleapis to the latest version :

`npm i googleapis@latest`

For more information related on how to Set Up Cloud Logging for Node.js using , please refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs)

Comment: yes, all dependencies are installed.  latest googleapis@latest is installed.  any more thoughts?